# gwt menu implementation

Tags: gwt, menu, menuitem, gwt2

I want to implement menu in GWT as shown on this website:

http://www.openkm.com/en/

I have created the menu system and I am able to display alerts from menu using following code:

```
Command cmd = new Command() {
  public void execute() {
    Window.alert("Menu item have been selected");
  }
}
```

I want to get rid of window.alert() and display my application pages from menu.

Answer (score 0):

First create an array list of views

```
public List<UIObject> viewsList = new ArrayList<UIObject>();
```

Add a view to that list

```
 viewsList.add(addMovieView);
```

Send the view you want to select to the helper method

```
public void changeView(UIObject selectedView) {
  for(UIObject view : viewsList) {
    if(selectedView.equals(view)) {
      view.setVisible(true);
    } else {
      view.setVisible(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create and load the appropriate page. For example if you use UiBinder then:

> ```
> MyPage selectedPage = new MyPage(); // creating of your panel
> RootPanel.get().clear(); // cleaning of rhe RootPanel    
> RootPanel.get().add(selectedPage); // adding the panel to the RootPanel
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make the entire page GWT, or just the menu? If it's just the menu, you will need to embed a GWT element into your overall HTML, then call something like

```
Window.open(linkURL, "_self", "");
```

from the appropriate menu items, which will navigate to another page.